# Simpler Golang Concurrency Pattern

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I've been trying to make a function that makes multiple external api calls concurrent with the following in mind

- return the first error encountered
- aggregate the results of the api call

Here is my function without concurrency

```
func GetMicrosoftTeamsChannelSuggestions(workspace *model.Workspace([]*model.MicrosoftTeamsChannel, error) {
    allChannels := []*model.MicrosoftTeamsChannel{}
    teamsGroups := GetMicrosoftTeamsGroupsFromWorkspace(workspace)

    for _, teamGroup := range teamsGroups {
        channels, err := GetMicrosoftTeamsChannels(*workspace.MicrosoftTeamsTenantId, teamGroup)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        allChannels = append(allChannels, channels...)
    }

    return allChannels, nil
}
```

My solution feels overkill. For one thing I kinda wished we could do away with the "crazy" for loop and the channel multiplexing thing with the select statement. I believe there is a simpler solution.

I read about concurrency patterns and tried to use one for this and produced the code below

```
func GetMicrosoftTeamsChannelSuggestions(workspace *model.Workspace) ([]*model.MicrosoftTeamsChannel, error) {
    allChannels := []*model.MicrosoftTeamsChannel{}
    teamsGroups := GetMicrosoftTeamsGroupsFromWorkspace(workspace)

    ch := make(chan []*model.MicrosoftTeamsChannel, len(teamsGroups))
    errCh := make(chan error)

    defer func() {
        close(ch)
        close(errCh)
    }()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(teamsGroups))

    for _, teamGroup := range teamsGroups {
        go func(teamGroup string) {
            defer wg.Done()

            channels, err := GetMicrosoftTeamsChannels(*workspace.MicrosoftTeamsTenantId, teamGroup)
            if err != nil {
                errCh <- err
            } else {
                ch <- channels
            }
        }(teamGroup)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    for {
        select {
        case channels := <-ch:
            allChannels = append(allChannels, channels...)
        case err := <-errCh:
            return nil, err // Return the first encountered error
        default:
            return allChannels, nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you facing any issue with the latter concurrent piece of code? It's as good as it gets imo.

Comment: @Adrian, given the function without concurrency, I felt the one with concurrency seemed a lot more complicated than it ought to be. I'm also inexperienced with concurrency. So my question is, can we do better(simpler) than the concurrency function I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will create many goroutines in a for-loop, and then pull the results after all of them are terminated. Also, the for-loop that waits for the results has a `default` case in the `select`, causing it to busy-loop. Also, even if one of the calls fail, they are all executed.

You can improve this solution. First, use a context to cancel, and a single channel to transfer both result and error:

```
type Result struct {
    Result []*model.MicrosoftTeamsChannel
    Err error
}

ctx, cancel:=context.WithCancel(context.Background())
ch:=make(chan Result) // No need for buffered channel
```

Setup a reader goroutine:

```
var err error
go func() {
   for result:=range ch {
      if ch.Err!=nil {
         cancel()
         if err!=nil { // Record the first error
             err=ch.Err
         }
      } else {
         allChannels = append(allChannels, result.Result...)
      }    
   }
}()
```

Then start the goroutines:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(len(teamsGroups))
for _, teamGroup := range teamsGroups {
    go func(teamGroup string) {
        defer wg.Done()
        // Stop if canceled
        if ctx.Err()!=nil {
           return
        }
        channels, err := GetMicrosoftTeamsChannels(*workspace.MicrosoftTeamsTenantId, teamGroup)
         ch<-Result{Result: channels, Err:err}
        }(teamGroup)
 }
```

Wait for them to end:

```
wg.Wait()
```

Close the channel so the reader can terminate:

```
close(ch)
```

Comment: The 'reader pattern' is quite simple and widely used. Even though it was still overkill for my implementation, it is a simpler solution to what I was attempting - that i didn't know abount prior to your answer. Thanks for helping out.